# Bitbucket Pipeline: Can we get a parameter value at the start of the build

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I just enabled the bitbucket pipeline and trying to do a POC but stuck at this two-point.

- I defined 2 stages build and deploy. But we have 3 environments and I am looking for a way a user can select an environment when he triggers a build from UI.(maybe some dropdown option)
- how to set parameters using if else condition in bitbucket pipeline. Basically, I am looking for a way to set.

```
if [ "${bucket}" == "test" ]; then
      s3=test.env
elif [ "${bucket}" == "app" ]; then
    s3=app.env
fi
```

now use $s3 in the step

Answer (score 0):

Simply export the variable:

`export s3=test.env`

Then, access it as usual using `$s3`.